# Save nightMode using switch

Tags: switch-statement, sharedpreferences, settings

I've just started Android studio for about a month now and come across a lot of problems but always have managed to find a solution.
This time I've red and tried a lot of things but now for 4 days I can't proceed, so finally I've decided to ask for help of the community.

What I'm trying to do is save nightmode and switch state in java.
So all I got right now is a switch and darkmode on my settings.java

AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightmode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);

So far I figured out that you can save, write and read from sharedPreferences

```
//Save 
SharedPreferences savePreferences = getSharedPreferences("filename", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = savePreferences.edit();

editor.putInt("value", Nightmode);
editor.apply();

//read
SharedPreferences savePreferences = getSharedPreferences("filename", MODE_PRIVATE);
savePreferences.getInt("value", Nightmode);
```

Already red the android docs but it didn't help, tried multiple tutorials, checked other topics but they did not provide the solution.

I tried putting AppcompatDelegate inside an int to use it inside SharedPreferences but I can't seem to get the full string/int inside it so I can work with it. Tried it with the switch and it worked but then I can't get it to work with Nightmode.

Help would be appreciated !! Here is my settings.java

```
public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        setTitle("settings");

        SwitchCompat switch2 = findViewById(R.id.switch2);

        // saves switch state + night mode

        SharedPreferences savePreferences = getSharedPreferences("saveState", 0);
        switch2.setChecked(savePreferences.getBoolean("value",false));
        int night = savePreferences.getInt("NightModeInt", 2);
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(night);

        switch2.setOnClickListener(v->{
                    if (switch2.isChecked()) {

                        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                        //save
                        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = savePreferences.edit();
                        edit.putBoolean("value", true);
                        edit.putInt("NightModeInt", 2 );

                        edit.apply();
                    } else {
                        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = savePreferences.edit();
                        edit.putBoolean("value", false);
                        edit.putInt("NightModeInt", 1 );
                        edit.apply();
                    }
        });
    }
}
```

(This is now working !!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        setTitle("settings");

        SwitchCompat switch2 = findViewById(R.id.switch2);

        // saves switch state + night mode

        SharedPreferences savePreferences = getSharedPreferences("saveState", 0);
        switch2.setChecked(savePreferences.getBoolean("value",false));
        int night = savePreferences.getInt("NightModeInt", 2);
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(night);

        switch2.setOnClickListener(v->{
                    if (switch2.isChecked()) {
                        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                        //save
                        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = savePreferences.edit();
                        edit.putBoolean("value", true);
                        edit.putInt("NightModeInt", 2 );

                        edit.apply();
                    } else {
                        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = savePreferences.edit();
                        edit.putBoolean("value", false);
                        edit.putInt("NightModeInt", 1 );
                        edit.apply();
                    }
        });
    }
}
```